# Is it possible to open man help file in gedit with a command?

Tags: ubuntu

it's hard to read ubuntu help, I hope I can read help in gedit editor.
is it possible to do the following ?
man ls   and open in gedit .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this function to get something similar:

```
man () { yelp "man:$@"; }
```

then `man ls` will open the man page in the help viewer.

`gnome-help`, which provides help in Gnome applications, is symlinked to `yelp`. The function above acts in place of the `man` program and calls `yelp` using the `man:` URI with the name of the command you provide as the argument. If you type `yelp man:ls` it will do the same thing as that function does if you provide "ls" as its argument.

Comment: can you explain the command ?

Comment: @Foolish: See my edit.

Comment: To see a page from a particular section, use something like `yelp 'man:stat(2)'`

Answer (score 4):

One possibility:

`file=$(mktemp) && man ls > $file && gedit $file`

This means 1) create a temporary file and assign its name to the variable "file", 2) dump the contents of "man ls" into it, and 3) open it in gedit.

It could also be done with the gedit external tools plugin, but the above is probably as easy as anything.

Comment: When I run it, this inserts screen formatting characters (backspaces etc) into the file shown in gedit.  There's probably some man/troff option to turn them off.